# UI not get updated if I use same formcontrol in parent child

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am facing a scenario in which I am using a **formGroup** in *parent component* and *child component*.
and I have placed same form control in parent and child but when I update value in parent, formgroup gets updated but value of control placed on child component do not get updated and vice versa. I have made a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znla5e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) Please guild me what I have to do if I want both parent and child component get updated ui if value is changed either from parent or from child.

Answer (score 1):

as discuses on this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10036) this is not wrong even if you in the same component if two input with the same formControlName only the one you are change will change.

there is a workaround on the child component

*app-child*

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.address.valueChanges.subscribe(val =>{
    this.address.patchValue(val,{emitEvent:false})
  })
}
```

any change from parent or child will trigger `form.patchValue` and that will update the UI

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcw5zv?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Doesn't it look like an infinite loop? Every time the address is changed, it patches the values, and patching the values will trigger `valueChanges` and so on.

Comment: {emitEvent:false} will prevent going to infinite cycle of event change